# docker error with multiple backend image install

Tags: java, python, node.js, docker

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /usr/src/rango
COPY ./ /usr/src/rango
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

here is my docker-compose file

```
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    working_dir: /usr/src/rango
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    tty: true
    links:
      - java
      - elasticsearch
      - node

  #java
  java:
    image: openjdk:9-jre

  #elastic search
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.0
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"

  node:
    image: node:10.13.0
```

Command i am using :

```
 sudo docker-compose up
```

when i am running command i am getting error as 
backend_node_1_26e7640d2fbb exited with code 0
backend_java_1_b1fbf7e151d7 exited with code 0

both node and java are not running .
i am using elastic search so i need java

plaese have look into my screenshot i have shared below.

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting the node and java images to do? You haven't configured them with any code to run.

Comment: java is for elastic search and node for react frontend

Comment: they should run in the background otherwise application won't run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dockers images are self-reliant in terms of the language runtime that they run on, meaning that they include everything that's needed to run the particular process (excluding external dependencies, such as database or other services).

Therefore, ElasticSearch images does not require a Java container, and similarly the Node container is not needed. They are exiting with 0 exit status (indicating that they run successfully to their completion) as you haven't specified a command to execute (and nor is there a default one defined in the base image).

In summary, you can remove the `java` and `node` services from your compose file.